# Javascript function to form then submit

Tags: javascript, ajax, geolocation

I have an issue with my code. I am a very basic user and so I'm struggling a great deal. What I am trying to achieve, is a button on my website, that gets a geolocation with `getLocationConstant()`, puts the geolocation into a form, and then sends a text message via a PHP script.

Currently, the Geolocation is populating the form, but when submitted, the form is blank. I can only assume that is because the JavaScript takes a moment to get the coordinates by which time the form has already submitted without data. Here is my code:

The process/logic I'm currently using is:

1. Submit button -> calls the JavaScript Geolocation and populates the form.
2. JavaScript which then runs a PHP script with EventListener, preventing Default settings.

The Geolocation is populated in the form, however the data in the form is not sent across to the PHP script for some reason. I can't give any further information on this issue, as this is the issue as I know it and the purpose for me posting here.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

    function getLocationConstant() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onGeoSuccess, onGeoError);
        } else {
            alert("Your browser or device doesn't support Geolocation");
        }
    }

    // If we have a successful location update
    function onGeoSuccess(event) {
        document.getElementById("message").value = "Hello, someone has scanned <?php echo $petname1 ?>'s tag. See the GPS location below: https://www.google.com/maps/place/" + event.coords.latitude + "," + event.coords.longitude;

    }

    // If something has gone wrong with the geolocation request
    function onGeoError(event) {
        alert("Error code " + event.code + ". " + event.message);
    }
    
</script>

  
<form id="sendmessage">
<textarea type="text" name="number" id="number" hidden><?php echo $phone ?></textarea>
<input type="text" id="message" name="message" value="">
<button type="submit" onclick="getLocationConstant()">Send GPS location to the owner</button>
</form>

<script>
const sendmessage = document.getElementById("sendmessage");

sendmessage.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    request.open("post", "send.php");
    request.onload = function () {
        console.log(request.responseText);
    }
    
    request.send(new FormData(sendmessage));
    
    
});

</script>
```

I've tried everything I possibly can with very limited knowledge.

Comment: Please share more details, start by debugging your code, check your browser console to check if it does there are any errors, check your PHP/Server logs.

Comment: Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem?

Comment: I've check the console, and the PHP script does run, but it throws an error stating that there is nothing in the message. If I click the submit button for a second time, it works perfectly fine because the data is now in the form.

Comment: I'm assuming a JS problem as the PHP script runs perfectly fine.

Comment: `getLocationConstant` is asynchronous, so there's no guarantee `onGeoSuccess` will be called before the `XMLHttpRequest` is created and sent ... `I've tried EVERYTHING I possibly can` like what?

Comment: "Assuming" sounds like you should check this further. And if you are facing any error message, please share it

Comment: So this issue has been closed before I can even get some help on the matter? Wonderful.

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it, such that others can understand your problem

Comment: It's closed because you didn't really provide a good enough set of details or a clear technical explanation of the code's behaviour, based on your debugging. That doesn't mean it can't be re-opened if you edit it sufficiently. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions for more info. See also [ask]. Questions need to be high-quality, to be beneficial for future readers (this site is actually an encylopaedia of useful programming info, it's not really a helpdesk or troubleshooting service, although we do try to assist people where we can).

Comment: So... `Submit Button -> Which Calls the JavaScript Geolocation and populated to a form.
JavaScript which then runs a .php script with EventListener, preventing Default settings.`....the problem is these steps need to run sequentially (so that the message will be populated into the input before the form is submitted), but you've coded it so that they'll run in parallel, and there's no guarantee that step 1 will complete before step 2 starts - in fact it's very unlikely.

Comment: Part of the problem is because you've used separate "click" and "submit" event handlers, which will both fire at the same time, rather than the more logical option of running the whole process through a single listener. Secondly, because the geoLocation operation is asynchronous and callback-based, you'd need to wait for that to complete before submitting anything, too. Some useful background reading on this kind of problem: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: No problem, thank you for your help. I've absolutely no idea how to fix it but I guess I'll try elsewhere :)

Comment: Don't go away, I'm getting to the point...be patient. You have to understand why it's like that, so you don't repeat the mistake elsewhere, as well as just being handed some working code.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see you was still replying.

Comment: Basically you need to structure it so it doesn't send the AJAX request until after the geolocation info has been collected. This demo doesn't actually work (because JSFiddle has disabled geolocation services) but it shows you how the code should be structured (there isn't room to post it in these comments, and I can't  write an answer while the question is closed): https://jsfiddle.net/k752gxsp/

Comment: That makes complete sense to me now, I would just never have been able to structure it in a working way. My knowledge on coding is so basic, I'm resorted to watching YT videos and looking at other peoples code and trying to put it all together in a way that I need. (I don't even know where to start learning this stuff for myself!) I have just used the code you've created, but still having issue, it appears that the form is submitting and that the preventDefault() isn't working correctly.

Comment: `I'm resorted to watching YT videos and looking at other peoples code`...no offence but that's probably one reason _why_ your knowledge is basic. Follow some proper introductory courses and structured tutorials to get the fundamental knowledge items in the right sequence, rather than jumping about on bits and pieces. and sadly from my experience what's on YT is often rather low-quality and not written by experts.

Comment: `it appears that the form is submitting and that the preventDefault() isn't working correctly`...have you checked in the browser's Developer Tools for any JS errors? Open the Console, make sure Preserve Log is ticked, run the code, and see if anything fails in the javascript. in the JSFiddle demo, at least, it definitely does handle the preventDefault correctly and doesn't submit (that's as far as the demo gets before we have a problem with the geolocation - which, again, shows that it's runnning the JS and not submitting the form)

Comment: You're absolutely right, time to start learning properly I think. Cancel my last message about the script not running properly, I just hadn't saved the page. Thank you for your help, it works now, you've been a massive help! Hopefully one day I won't need it!

Comment: No worries. I also always suggest the old-fashioned approach of buying a book about your chosen subject as well. It's what we _had_ to do when I was learning, because online resources weren't well-developed enough to do without it, but it still gives you a solid foundation from a reputable source, and means you work through the things you need to know in a logical order, hopefully without leaving any gaps. And you've got an index of important things you can refer to and look up if you hit a roadblock.

Comment: All noted. Well if you're ever in the business of becoming a mentor then let me know, if not then I'll bid farewell with one last thank you haha.